# Max size of docs sent via JSON to SOLR for indexing

Tags: json, solr

I have a solr instance that gets its data from mysql via cron / python scripts.  Right now, it sends 1000 documents at a time.  What's the maximum number I can send without problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solr does not have any such limit on max number of document to be indexed in a single load. This will be limited by the memory allocated to the JVM, which is running the Solr instance. I have personally tried with 50K document at once, given java heap memory was 24GB. The advantage of doing the bulk load saving the network latency time.